# Serve JSON from index action to index.html in public folder

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, node.js, jspm

I'm trying to create a single page application using Rails as the backend as this is the only backend framework I know. I put all my files in the public folder and also installed npm and jspm so I can use javascript functionality.

What I'm trying to do is have this index action in my movies controller

```
  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
    render :json => @movies
  end
```

send the collection of movies as JSON data to index.html file located in the public folder. I'm using the 'fetch' function to retrieve the data in my client.js file:

```
let api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'

fetch(api_url).then(function(resp) {
  resp.json().then(function(movies) {
    console.log(movies)
  })
})
```

This results in the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I'm not sure what this means and if I'm even going about this correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you get all movies in index method of controller?

Comment: i think your api url is main problem?

Comment: Yes, I assigned all the movies to the @movies variable in the index action.

Comment: I have a route set as: root 'movies#index'. The api_url variable should be valid, no?

Comment: when using browser, how do u see data ?

Comment: ya check it in browser what it return in response

Comment: try `curl http://127.0.0.1:3000`, do you fetch JSON object ?

Comment: type curl http://127.0.0.1:3000 in the command line?

Comment: yes, in command line.

Comment: dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/sm/pkg/versions/openssl/1.0.1e/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5

Comment: Not sure what that means

Comment: try this one `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:application/json" -X GET http://localhost:3000`

Comment: ohh also, in `application_controller.rb`  add this one `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }`

Comment: let me know, what kind a data u getting there.

Comment: Sorry man same error

Comment: where is your `  def index
    @movies = Movie.all
    render :json => @movies
  end` located, in what controller ? and can i see your `routes.rb` file ?

Comment: That action is located in the MoviesController.

Comment: root 'movies#index'

  resources :movies do
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :users, only: [:show, :create]

  get '/signup' => 'users#new'

  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'

  post '/login' => 'sessions#create'

  delete '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

Comment: alright, everything works on mine. Can you goto `localhost:3000` in browser. Do u see objects ?

Comment: No if I use localhost:3000 I get the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error. That's why I set api_url to http://127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: what does Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < even mean? Where is this token? The console says undefined:1

Comment: can you post that `server console log` error ?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the server log

Comment: ist in github ? give me a link. I am really wonder

Comment: https://github.com/hbanait7/ftv2. Changed @movie variable to now_playing

Comment: Thanks for your help @7urkm3n, I appreciate it.

Comment: where is your `let api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000'` code located ?

Comment: public/src/client.js

Comment: also u have one more bug in DB columns. lets fix this one first. goto command line and try this again `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type:application/json" -X GET http://localhost:3000/movies` You will see now data fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
let api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/movies'
```

Both the same:

```
fetch(api_url).then(function(resp) {
  resp.json().then(function(movies) {
    console.log(movies)
  })
})
```

OR

```
fetch(api_url).then(r => r.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(e => console.log('error'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain why adding '/movies' to http://127.0.0.1:3000 allowed the data to be returned?

Comment: your `root 'movies#index'` is not responding anything. you have `resource :movies` use that one.

Comment: also, you have DB column bug, if run  `rake db:migrate:reset` yr able to see that bug too.

Comment: Yes, thanks I will address that now. Thank you for all your help!